# Unexpected behaviour using bit-fields and unions

Tags: c++, bit, unions, bit-fields

I was experimenting with bit-fields and unions and created this:

```cpp
union REG{
    struct{
        char posX: 7;
        char posY: 7;
        unsigned char dir:  2;
    };

    unsigned short reg;
};
```

And when I run `sizeof( short )`, I get 2, but when I run `sizeof( REG )`, I get 4. That's weird to me because when I sum the bits I get 7+7+2=16, which is the size in bits of a 2 byte datatype.

I'm currently using the Dev-C++ editor with compiler `TDM-GCC 9.9.2 64-bit Debug`.

This is my first question, so please tell me if you need more information... **Thanks in advance!**

**Edit:** Upon further experimentation I realized the size is the same (2 bytes) when I set the size of posX and posY to 6 bits. But that still puzzles because the sum is 14 bits which is less than 2 bytes...

**Edit 2:** Thanks to AviBerger I realized that replacing the char/unsigned char datatype with short/unsigned short the result of '''sizeof( REG )''' turns into 2. But I still can't figure out **"Why does this happen?"**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you use short as the type of the bitfields?

Comment: See: [on some platforms, bit fields don't straddle bytes, on others they do](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

Comment: @AviBerger It actually worked using the short datatype, but i still don't understand why, I'm about to read the link you shared

Comment: I fiddled a bit on [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec010123aab42eae). I strongly guess you cannot pack 7 + 7 + 2 bits into `char` or `unsigned char` (nor can you 7 + 7 or 7 + 2). Hence, bits are not packed tight. This is different with `unsigned short` which provides at least 16 bits (per standard).

Comment: The best about this, I found in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field): _If the specified size of the bit field is greater than the size of its type, the value is limited by the type: `a std::uint8_t b : 1000;` would still hold values between 0 and 255. the extra bits become unused padding._ and _Multiple adjacent bit fields are usually packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined)_ ;-)

Comment: @Scheff yeah, also read that, but i don't think this helps here because each bit field is assigned a size of, at most, 7 bits which is less than a byte (size of char) so I thought that shouldn't cause any problems, clearly I was wrong, as seen in edit 2...

Comment: It appears the implementation you are using will not straddle a bit field across 2 different chars when char is the declared type. As Scheff implied, it puts a 7 field in the first char, a 7 field in the second char, a 2 field in the third (and adds a fourth for padding for alignment purposes). If your field sizes were 5, 3, and 7, I predict it would be 2 bytes as the 5 & 3 would fit in a single byte not crossing a char boundary. When you switch to short, it all fits in a single short. However, as @Scheff indicated, this is implementation defined. Different compilers could do it differently.

Answer (score 2):

From the spec we have

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-
>   field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
>   structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
>   implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
>   low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
>   addressable storage unit is unspecified.

So the actual behavior depends on what size allocation unit the compiler chooses for the bitfields, and whether it allows fields to span mulitple allocation units.  This choice is implementation defined, but a common implementation is to use the declared type of the bit field as the allocation unit, and not allow crossing allocation unit boundaries.  So when you use (unisgned) char, it uses an 8-bit allocation unit.  This means that no two of the bitfields can be combined into a single byte (7+7 > 8 and 7+2 > 8), so it ends up taking 3 allocation units (bytes), which then rounds up to 4 for alignment when combined with a short in the union.

When you change the bitfield size to 6, now the second and third bitfields can fit in a byte (6+2 = 8), so it only takes two allocation units.

When you change the bitfield type to `short` it uses a 16-bit allocation unit, so all 3 bitfields can fit in one allocation unit.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points of finesse when working with `struct` and `union`.  The most common is that fields are generously padded to be aligned to the CPU's word size.

```
struct {
     char   c1;
     char   c2;
} s1;
```

seems like it should be a two byte structure, but surprisingly often `sizeof (s1)` will be not 2, but 4—or even 8.  This was the case even in the 1980s with 16-bit machines.

This is because C and C++ compilers will align each `char` element of a structure to a two byte or four byte boundary.  I have yet to see structure elements aligned to 8 byte boundary, but we haven't got 64 bit architecture being that needy—yet.

The solution is to invoke a compilation option to "pack structures".  This can either be done on the compiler command line or including a suitable #pragma option before the structure declaration:

```
#pragma pack(1)   // this particular syntax is valid for many compilers

struct {
     char  c11;
     char  c12;
} s2;

#pragma pack(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the standard (n4835):

> **11.4.9 Bit-ﬁelds [class.bit]**
>   1 [...] Allocation of bit-ﬁelds within a class object is implementation-deﬁned. Alignment of bit-ﬁelds is implementation-deﬁned. Bit-ﬁelds are packed into some addressable allocation unit. [Note: Bit-ﬁelds straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others. Bit-ﬁelds are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note]

As you see the size and alignment are implementation defined. So you might get the expected behaviour on other compilers/platforms, but on your compiler/platform you get different results than you expect.