# C++ 14 - union - Is it legal to access inactive member?

Tags: c++, c++14, union, bit-fields

After read a lot about it, I'm confused about if it is legal or not accessing to inactive member of an union starting from C++14. I understood it is undefined behaviour up to C++11.

Some references:

[Unexpected behaviour using bit-fields and unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825323/unexpected-behaviour-using-bit-fields-and-unions)

[Is it legal to use address of one field of a union to access another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056403/is-it-legal-to-use-address-of-one-field-of-a-union-to-access-another-field)

C++14 introduced this statement:

*"all non-static data members will have the same address"*

(ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Is it admissible to use an union like this?

```
typedef union _BYTE_VAL_T
{
    unsigned char Val;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char b0:1;
        unsigned char b1:1;
        unsigned char b2:1;
        unsigned char b3:1;
        unsigned char b4:1;
        unsigned char b5:1;
        unsigned char b6:1;
        unsigned char b7:1;
    } bits;
} BYTE_BITS_T;


int main()
{
   BYTE_BITS_T reg;
   reg.bits.b5 = 0x1;
   std::cout << reg.Val; // use of inactive member
}
```

Comment: In recent C++ releases the rules about what you can and cannot alias have been loosening around stuff that's provably similar. A lot of this is because even though it may have been undefined behaviour, the results were dead predictable on any sane implementation and target hardware. That said, the `union`'s type-punning rules are still extremely strict and simple: Don't do it.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_BYTE_VAL_T`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: Also note that the C language is significantly more open to punning. For some tricks you can include a module of C that is called from C++ and be compliant.

Comment: In C++ you don’t have to do that `typedef` dance. `union BYTE_BITS_T` works just fine.

Comment: See [C++ Latest Draft - \[class.union\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union) - less than an example of clarity.

Comment: *"C++14 introduced this statement:

'all non-static data members will have the same address'

(ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)"* -- Continuing this quote to the next sentence (which is not qualified by C++ version) on cppreference.com: *"It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written."* What is ambiguous about this?

Comment: Your second reference ([Is it legal to use address of one field of a union to access another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33056403)) was posted in 2015 and lacks a version-specific tag. That implies that the question is about C++14 (the latest released standard at the time), and in fact the accepted answer begins by asserting the C++14 information you presented. How is your question different than that one?